# Dyanmically associate schema name from an external properties file in JPA?

Tags: jpa

I want different schema name for each of my entity classes to be associated at runtime before creating entity manager factory in simple jpa application,

Comment: Please share more information, what have you tried so far? Thanks!

Comment: Plz anybody help me, I want the schema name should come from a external properties file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your JPA provider is, however, if you are flexible EclipseLink has Multi-Tenancy capabilities. One of the options allows a Table-Per-Tenant scenario and the Schema can be used as a discriminator. This allows the same table name and layout to be used in the different schemas and the contextProperty for the schema can be set with your persistence-unit config in the xml file (as one example).

Here are two links, the first describes the feature and the second is a wiki with some examples.

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/solutions/multitenancy003.htm#A1235913
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant

Comment: Thank you,I am using Hibernate-JPA-EJB 3.0-Persistence.jar. I have declared all the Entity classes in different packages,I want that Database name i should provide at runtime before entity manager factory is created.And the database name must come from a Properties file which is inside some other path.